# Can't run the ef command with Core 3.0 ASP.NET

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer PowerShell v16.3.9
** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
PS C:\Users\aa\source\repos\net-app> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
PS C:\Users\aa\source\repos\net-app> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0
Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.
PS C:\Users\aa\source\repos\net-app> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
PS C:\Users\aa\source\repos\net-app>
```

Ok, so I tried to install the ef migration tool and run:

dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate

but obviously there's something wrong. Installing in the global scope, shouldn't it create a reference on the PATH? What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: goto to the package manager console type : add-migration initialcreate

Comment: PM> add-migration initialcreate
add-migration : The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ add-migration initialcreate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (add-migration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to [install EF tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) with:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```